# Combining fields from multiple arrays to a single object

Tags: jq

What I need is simply to extract **id**, **sales** from **sorted_employees** AND **full name** for that employee from **employees**.. like this:

```json
{ "Full name": "John Doe", "ID": "employee1", "Sales": "26" }
{ "Full name": "Sam Jones", "ID": "employee2", "Sales": "119" }
```

What would be the easiest way to combine these 2 arrays ( employees & sorted_employees ) ? I have problems merging the result, I have tried to cast results into an array and I tried purely with jq filters.. but it doesn't want to give me what I need..

```sh
employees_id=$( echo "${json_data}" | jq -r '.employees[] | .id' )
sorted_employees_id=$( echo "${json_data}" | jq -r '.sorted_employees[] | .id' )
sorted_employees_sales=$( echo "${json_data}" | jq '.sorted_employees[] | .sales' )
```

```json
{
    "employees": [ {
       "started_at": "2018-05-01 12.00",
       "id": "employee1",
       "facebook": "https://fb/john_doe",
       "full name": "John Doe"
    }, {
       "started_at": "2017-05-01 12.00",
       "id": "employee2",
       "facebook": "https://fb/sam_jones",
       "full name": "Sam Jones"
    }, {
       "started_at": "2016-05-01 12.00",
       "id": "employee3",
       "facebook": "https://fb/jane_roe",
       "full name": "Jane Roe"

    }],
    "sorted_employees": [{
        "id": "employee1",
        "sales": 26
    }, {
        "id": "employee2",
        "sales": 119
    }, {
        "id": "employee3",
        "sales": 84
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could combine the two arrays and just group by the common ID field and form the desired output object

```
jq '.employees + .sorted_employees | group_by(.id) | 
  map({"Full name": .[0]."full name", ID: .[0].id, "Sales": .[1].sales})'
```

Comment: Yes, that solution works. But now when the values are mapped, how do I reach them outside the jq command? For ex, I would like to loop through the result and select  Full name, id , sales WHERE sales > 100? .. And then cast it to a new variable/array for ex..

Comment: You can filter further by doing it in `jq` itself - `jq 'map(select(.Sales > 100))'`